# Let code run after logout

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, nohup

I have a long code that extracts data from a file, stores it in a dictionary, and inserts it into a mysql table. I need to loop this over a folder of nearly 1000 files, and this will take hours. I have seen a lot of conflicting advice and am not sure which is the simplest and most safe. Is there a command I can run that'll let the code keep running even if I log out of my user on the computer (which means the terminals will be quit out of)? I have not started running it yet.

Comment: This question has already been [asked](https://superuser.com/questions/282350/how-do-i-run-a-script-in-the-background-and-leave-it-running-when-i-log-out) on SuperUser. Dunno if it's worth migrating just to be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your code in a `screen` or on `tmux`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you code is currently run like `./ingest-data.py`, so the simplest option is to prefix with [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) (short for no-hangup).

```
nohup ./ingest-data.py
```

To save debugging output if your shell drops, you'll need to redirect `nohup` output to files. The [Gnu Bash Redirection manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) has more details.

```
nohup ./ingest-data.py >output 2>&1 &
```

Alternatively terminal multiplexers (like `tmux` or `byobu`) can be detached and reattached to manually, but will also persist if the shell connection drops. If you spend a lot of time in terminals then other features might interest you, so check some articles and videos to gauge your interest.

A third option is desktop detach/reattach with X2Go or NoMachine but might require more tuning than you have available with your current project.

Start with `nohup`, move to other tools if you're inclined to.